# React Router 4 in Meteor project works on reload, but not when clicking on a link

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm following this React Router 4 tutorial to add routes to my Meteor / React project:

https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

When I click links, the URL changes as expected but the route content doesn't appear. If I refresh the page then the route content loads correctly. Here's my code:

Versions: METEOR@1.6.0.1, react-router-dom@4.2.2

main.js

````
``` JSX
import React from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// Start the app with imports
import '../imports/startup/accounts-config.js';
import App from '../imports/ui/layouts/App.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    render((<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('app'));
});
```
````

App.js

````
``` JSX

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

// game components
import { MapSquares } from '../../api/map/map.js';

// User Accounts
import AccountsUIWrapper from '../AccountsUIWrapper.jsx';

import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../pages/home';
import Roster from '../pages/roster';
import Schedule from '../pages/schedule';

function MapSquare(props) {
    return (
        <span className="mapsquare" key={props.index}>{props.row}, {props.column}</span>
    );
}

class App extends Component {
    renderMapSquare(mapsquare) {
        return (
            <MapSquare
                index={mapsquare._id}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        // avoid error while loading data
        let data = [];
        if (typeof this.props.mapsquares !== 'undefined') {
            data = this.props.mapsquares;
        }

        let rows = [];
        let index = 0;

        if (data.length !== 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                let thisrow = [];
                for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    let source = data[index];
                    let newthing = <MapSquare
                        key={source._id}
                        row={source.row}
                        column={source.column}
                    />;
                    thisrow.push(newthing);
                    index++;
                }
                rows.push(<div className="map-row" key={i}>{thisrow}</div>);
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="game">
                <AccountsUIWrapper />
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to='/roster'>Roster</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to='/schedule'>Schedule</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
                    <Route path='/schedule' component={Schedule}/>
                </Switch>
                <div className="game-map">
                    {rows}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// provides data to component App
export default withTracker(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('mapsquares');

    return {
        'mapsquares': MapSquares.find({}, { 'sort': { 'row': 1, 'column': 1 } }).fetch(),
    };
})(App);

```
````

home.js (the roster and schedule pages work the same way)

````
``` JSX
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
);
export default Home;

```
````

Any idea what I'm missing here? It so nearly works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping my data container in withRouter seems to have done the trick:

App.js:

````
``` JSX
import { withRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export default withRouter(withTracker(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('mapsquares');

    return {
        'mapsquares': MapSquares.find({}, { 'sort': { 'row': 1, 'column': 1 } }).fetch(),
    };
})(App));
```
````

See the docs:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter